# Is it wrong to pronounce the second "T" in word "potential"?

Tags: pronunciation

Why shouldn't we pronounce the second "T" in word "potential"?
Any english rule about "t" in words?

Comment: You do pronounce it.  Just not as a "hard" T.

Comment: [pə'tenʃl]  right?

Comment: The same as prudential, essential, credential, tangential, confidential.  The "-tial" ending is generally pronounced as "shul".  If you didn't pronounce the T, it would sound like "ee-ul".

Comment: Got it. Thank you. I should remember the "-tial"'s pronounce.

Comment: Although this post has been re-opened, the original poster found the following question useful, and I think other visitors to this page might as well: [What rules of English allow the first t in “patient” to make an sh sound?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4737)

Answer (score 8):

*Potential* is usually pronounced  /pə'tenʃl/. However, many native speakers, and learners as well, will put a /t/ in  between the /n/ and the following /ʃ/. This is called  /t/-epenthesis.

This phenomenon will happen very often in English when we have  /n/ followed by  /ʃ/. So it is perfectly possible to say /pə'tentʃl/ in English. However, notice that this is not because there is a T in the writing. We also find an epenthetic /t/ in words like *mensh* where there is no orthographic T, no written T,  between the N and the following SH, which represents the /ʃ/ phoneme.

An epenthetic /t/ is caused by the velum rising to make the /ʃ/ sound before the oral closure for the /n/ has been released. In other words, as we pass from making the nasal sound to making the 'sh' sound, our tongue and velum may be slightly out of sync. In the in-between phase the articulation becomes the same as that for a /t/, and so we get an incidental /t/ in the word.

We find the same thing when we get /n/ before an /s/, so the following words sound identical for many speakers:

- mince/mints
- prince/prints

Comment: As a student of linguistics, do you know of any language with minimal pairs /nts/,/ns/ in any language? (which is to say, if you haven't figured, that I don't think there is any articulatory or perception difference at all for anybody).

Comment: @Mitch: There certainly are. Some varieties of English have had, or still have, the distinction.

Comment: @suməlic Oh. Can you give some examples of those varieties and the words that have different meanings with only that one change?

Comment: @Mitch: [John Wells](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2010/08/some-day-my-prints-will-come.html) for example has written that he distinguishes "prince" and "prints."

Comment: @suməlic Good example and Wells would be the best of anybody to know. But even so I find that hard to believe even in the most articulate of speech.

Comment: @Mitch Well, there are definitely  languages which won't allow a /nts/ cluster. I deeply susect that some of those will allow a /ns/ cluster. I doubt that kind of epenthesis will happen there. But, I don't know. For sure there wouldn't be an /nts/ in those speakers' phonemic inventory, although there mights be a [nts] in the sound. A Sumelic says, Wells - and other individual speakers - will definitely find *mince* and *mints* to be minimal pairs. Good question though. As for the other languages, I'm just speculating.

Comment: Your answer does explain **how** _potential_ is pronounced, but how about **why** (as asked) ?

Comment: @Irhala "An epenthetic /t/ is caused by the velum rising to make the /ʃ/ sound before the oral closure for the /n/ has been released. " <-- In other words, as we pass from making the nasal sound to making the 'sh' sound, our tongue and velum may be slightly out of sync. In the in between phase the articulation become the same as that for a /t/, and so we get an incidental /t/ in the word.

Comment: Add this to your answer and it'll be perfect.

Comment: @Irhala That quote *was* form my post! :)

Comment: I meant, add the "so we get an incidental /t/ in the word" part.

Comment: @Irhala I'm just going into a lesson now. Will sort it when I get out. Thanks!

Comment: @Mitch If you’ll accept non-tautosyllabic examples, the asker’s own native language (I’m assuming that’s Mandarin) has a very clear distinction between /ns/ and /nts/. /ts/ (transliterated ⟨c⟩ in Pinyin) is a single consonant in Mandarin, distinguished from /s/, so something like 单色 _dānsè_ ‘monochromatic’ is [ˈd̥an˥sɤ˦˩], while something like 单侧 _dāncè_ ‘unilateral’ is [ˈd̥an˥tsɤ˦˩]. Even without going that far afield, German has pairs like _eins_ [aɪ̯ns] vs. Mainz [maɪ̯nts]. Unlike in English, I’ve never heard [aɪ̯nts] or [maɪ̯ns] for either of those.